# Laravel Undefined offset: 1

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I want to add a authentication when guest try to access the home page.  I get the error when I try to access the home page.

**Laravel Version : Laravel 5**

**The routes.php error version:**

```
Route::get('auth/login', 'Auth\AuthController@getLogin');  
Route::post('auth/login', 'Auth\AuthController@postLogin');  
Route::get('auth/logout', 'Auth\AuthController@getLogout');
Route::get('auth/register', 'Auth\AuthController@getRegister'); 
Route::post('auth/register', 'Auth\AuthController@postRegister'); 
Route::get('/', ['middleware' => 'auth', function()
{
    Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index'); 
    Route::get('pages/{id}', 'PagesController@show');  
    Route::post('comment/store', 'CommentsController@store'); 
}]);

Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin', 'namespace' => 'Admin', 'middleware' =>     'auth'], function()  
{
  Route::get('/', 'AdminHomeController@index');
  Route::resource('pages', 'PagesController');
  Route::resource('comments', 'CommentsController');
});
```

**Error Log**

```
at HandleExceptions->handleError('8', 'Undefined offset: 1',   'G:\wamp\www\Laravel5\vendor\compiled.php', '7377', array('request' => object(Request), 'this' => object(Route))) in compiled.php line 7377
```

**The correct origional version**

```
Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index');  
Route::get('pages/{id}', 'PagesController@show');  
Route::post('comment/store', 'CommentsController@store'); 
Route::get('auth/login', 'Auth\AuthController@getLogin');  
Route::post('auth/login', 'Auth\AuthController@postLogin');  
Route::get('auth/logout', 'Auth\AuthController@getLogout');
Route::get('auth/register', 'Auth\AuthController@getRegister'); 
Route::post('auth/register', 'Auth\AuthController@postRegister'); 
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin', 'namespace' => 'Admin', 'middleware' =>  'auth'], function()  
{
  Route::get('/', 'AdminHomeController@index');
  Route::resource('pages', 'PagesController');
  Route::resource('comments', 'CommentsController');
});
```

**Update:**
I know solve the problem but don't know why? You can see the last four lines I declared a route group with authentication. And when I test that part, I had logged in. Now I log out the `/admin` prefix and I can see the login page when I try to access the root url.

So my idea is write a guestAuth middleware for users and a adminAuth middleware to administrators. **Do you have better ideas?**

Comment: The error might be because of some controller or view code.

Comment: Is There any problem with my routes.php? I just not sure.

Comment: Do you need more Log?

Comment: Fine, I will check other parts.

Comment: I mean, I even can't see the authenticate page. when I try to access the root url, it crash down.

Comment: @sgt I know solve the problem but don't know why? you can see the last three lines I declare a route group with authentication. and When I test that part, I had logged in. Now I log out the `/admin` prefix and I can see the login page when I try to access the root url.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with -

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function()
{
    Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index'); 
    Route::get('pages/{id}', 'PagesController@show');  
    Route::post('comment/store', 'CommentsController@store'); 
});
```

Check [here](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/routing#route-groups)

Comment: `ErrorException in compiled.php line 6878:  Argument 2 passed to Illuminate\Routing\Router::group() must be an instance of Closure, none given, called in G:\wamp\www\Laravel5\vendor\compiled.php on line 5360 and defined` syntax error?

Comment: Am not sure about that.

Comment: @TalkingHeads A Little different and sgt's code test passed. accepted. Thank you all.

Comment: @TalkingHeads `grouping` will allow the middleware to be implemented for that routes.

Answer (score 1):

Is it this line of code?

```
Route::get('/', ['middleware' => 'auth', function()
{
    Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index'); 
    Route::get('pages/{id}', 'PagesController@show');  
    Route::post('comment/store', 'CommentsController@store'); 
}]);
```

Should it be?

```
Route::get('/', ['middleware' => 'auth'], function()
    {
        Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index'); 
        Route::get('pages/{id}', 'PagesController@show');  
        Route::post('comment/store', 'CommentsController@store'); 
    });
```

Comment: You Are Right !!! I can't find the reference in docs. Can you tell me where it from?

Comment: No No No, still a problem. I can see the login page but if I type email and passwd and log in. There still `Undefined offset: 1` same as my question's error log.